# Triangle Primitives Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing, gl-triangle-strip

Is there a possibility to draw on the canvas of HTML page the gradient primitives?

An example of what I want (I did it in another programming language):

[image]

(excuse me for my English, if I do not write correctly)

Comment: Yes, using the Canvas API. Do you have a specific question about the API?

Comment: I found only information about linear and radial gradient.
I do not know how to use the triangular gradient.

Comment: You probably want to use a WebGL context, not a 2D context.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This tutorial is exactly as you want to do:
http://www.nixtu.info/2010/08/html5-canvas-gradients-triangle.html